# Fusion of multiple 3D binary arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I am looking for an efficient way to fuse multiple (N) binary 3D arrays of the same shape. I.e. the resulting fused array should have for each coordinate a value that is obtained by a majority vote among all values at the corresponding coordinate of the N arrays.

E.g. a toy 1D case:

```
[0,0,1] - 1st array 
[0,1,1] - 2d array 
[0,0,0] - ...
[0,1,0] - ...
[1,0,1] - Nth array
-------
[0,0,1] - fused array
```

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to do a sum reduction along the rows, find the location of the max, and assign that index a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scipy.stats.mode`, which will take an array of your 3D arrays as input.
An example with 2D arrays is:

```
arrs = [[[0,1,0],[0,0,0]],
        [[1,1,0],[0,0,1]],
        [[1,0,1],[1,0,0]]]
scipy.stats.mode(arrs).mode
>>> array([[[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]])
```